# Last mysql reboot

Tags: mysql, linux

Is there a way to check the last restart of mysql server, in global variables or something else ?

System : redhat

Logging : not activated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Uptime';`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Uptime

Answer (score 3):

The number of seconds that the server has been up.

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Uptime';
```

The number of seconds since the most recent FLUSH STATUS statement.

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS like 'uptime_since_flush_status';
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is :

```
ps -ef|grep mysqld
```

then check

```
STIME
```

which is the last start time .